# About the baseline difference between UILabel and UIButtonLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, uilabel

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the padding at the top and bottom of the UIButtonLabel is strange.

I want the text to always be centered as in UILabel.
Here is my code:

```swift
extension UILabel {
    func apply(lineHeight: CGFloat, letterSpacing: CGFloat = 0) {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text ?? " ")
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
        
        // Line Height
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight
        style.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight
        attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: range)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.baselineOffset, value: (lineHeight - font.lineHeight) / 2, range: range)
        
        // Letter Spacing
        attributedString.addAttribute(.kern, value: letterSpacing, range: range)
        
        attributedText = attributedString
    }
}

label.apply(lineHeight: 24)
button.titleLabel.apply(lineHeight: 24)
```

Comment: you can not use private function in extension to outside

Comment: thanks. I edit that code. But that is not the cause of this problem. @RezaKhonsari

Comment: Button has insets or padding please remove it's padding and check if you're problem is gone:

        button.titleLabel?.apply(lineHeight: 24) \n
        var buttonConfig = UIButton.Configuration.plain() \n
        buttonConfig.contentInsets = .zero \n
        button.configuration = buttonConfig \n
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: [])

Comment: exactly same result :-( @RezaKhonsari

Comment: also could you add these lines
        buttonConfig.imagePadding = 0
        buttonConfig.titlePadding = 0

Comment: last code I sent for you works on my project

Comment: Sadly it's still the same. Even the current test is an iOS 14 device, so Button Configuration cannot be applied... @RezaKhonsari

Comment: Maybe try `button.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters`

Comment: @ShawnFrank :-( It's still same...

Comment: @oddK -- are you *sure* you don't have something else going on that would affect the button and label? I just gave your extension a try, and this is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0co2Y.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/itQe4.png ... the Top pair has the label centered on the button, the bottom pair has the label only partially covering the button.

Comment: @DonMag Actually add something else. Change the font. But both the buttons and labels are the same font, even the same size and weight.

Comment: @oddK - OK, you'll need to provide complete information. Just tried it with a couple different fonts and cannot reproduce the issue you're seeing.

Comment: I re upload question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71259838/10283519