# How to adjust vertical center in UILabel?

Tags: uilabel, nsattributedstring

I made function that set line height and letter spacing in `UILabel`.

```swift
extension UILabel {
    func apply(lineHeight: CGFloat, letterSpacing: CGFloat = 0) {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text ?? " ")
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
        
        // Line Height
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight
        style.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight
        attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: range)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.baselineOffset, value: (lineHeight - font.lineHeight) / 2, range: range)
        
        // Letter Spacing
        attributedString.addAttribute(.kern, value: letterSpacing, range: range)
        
        attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

And I apply that my label.

But something very strange happens.

All of the codes below are the same.

The only difference is when you change the label's text.

I can't understand why this is happening.

What's the problem?

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        let label1 = UILabel()
        label1.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .bold)
        label1.apply(lineHeight: 48)
        label1.text = "This is test1"
        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let label2 = UILabel()
        label2.text = "This is test2"
        label2.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .bold)
        label2.apply(lineHeight: 48)
        label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let label3 = UILabel()
        label3.text = "This is test3"
        label3.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .bold)
        label3.apply(lineHeight: 48)
        label3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(label1)
        view.addSubview(label2)
        view.addSubview(label3)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            label1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            
            label2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            label2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.centerXAnchor),
            
            label3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            label3.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.centerXAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be considered a "bug" - worth reporting.

If you set the `.text` property ***after*** setting the attributed text, the line height in the paragraph style does not get applied.

You can confirm this by adding this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let v = view.subviews[1] as? UILabel {
        v.text = "This is test2"
    }
}
```

When you tap the view, your 2nd label will "lose" it's line height setting.

Curiously, the way around this is to ***reference*** the label's `.attributedText` property after setting its `.text` property:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let v = view.subviews[1] as? UILabel {
        v.text = "This is test2"
        _ = v.attributedText
    }
}
```

which, apparently, will cause UIKit to "update" the paragraph line height style.

So, for your specific example, adding this at the end of `viewDidLoad()`:

```
[label1, label2, label3].forEach { v in
    _ = v.attributedText
}
```

will result in all 3 labels having the same appearance.